# Каким методом в Laravel , лучше извлекать изображения из базы данных Storage::url() или asset()?

Tags: php, laravel

Методы `Storage::url($path)`   и метод `asset($path)`  одинаково хорошо показываю изображения , заметил разницу только в пути  image src .

Какой из этих функции выбрать для показа изображения ?

Объясните пожалуйста разницу между  `Storage::url` и `asset()`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### assets()

когда файл сохранён и создана символьная ссылка, вы можете создать URL к файлу с помощью вспомогательной функции asset():

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

### Storage::url()

При использовании драйвера local или s3 вы можете использовать метод url() для получения URL для файла. При использовании драйвера local в начало пути к файлу будет просто подставлено /storage, и будет возвращён относительный URL. При использовании драйвера s3 будет возвращён полный удалённый URL:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file1.jpg');
```

> При использовании драйвера local все файлы, которые должны быть
>   общедоступны, необходимо помещать в каталог storage/app/public. Кроме
>   того, вам надо создать символьную ссылку в public/storage, которая
>   указывает на папку storage/app/public.